# jQuery Datatable not rendering the data properly

Tags: jquery, typescript, datatables

I am trying to display data in jquery datatable but, for some reason, I am seeing a background image for half of the records. This image goes away and the grid is back to normal if I click on sorting icon in any of the columns.

Note: I am using dataTables.scroller.js extension.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Report 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table id="Report1" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Report 1 Info</th>
                        <th>Column 1</th>
                        <th>Column 2</th>
                        <th>Column 3</th>
                        <th>Column 4</th>
                        <th>Column 5</th>
                        <th>Column 6</th>
                        <th>Column 7</th>
                        <th>Column 8</th>
                        <th>Column 9</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
class Report1Component {

    report1: any = $('#Report1');    

    public ShowGrid() {

        this.report1.DataTable({
            deferRender: true,
            scrollY: 600,
            "scrollX": true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            scroller: true,
            columns: [
                { data: "ReportData" },
                { data: "Column1" },
                { data: "Column2" },
                { data: "Column3." },
                { data: "Column4" },
                { data: "Column5" },
                { data: "Column6" },
                { data: "Column7" },
                { data: "Column8" },
                { data: "Column9" }
            ]
        });
    }

    public LoadData() {

        var instance = this;

        instance.report1.dataTable().fnClearTable();

        $.when(Report1Service.GetData())
            .done(function (response) {

                instance.report1.dataTable().fnAddData(response);            

            }).always(function () {

                instance.report1.dataTable().fnDraw();

            });
    }
}

$(function () {
    var report1Component = new Report1Component();

    report1Component.ShowGrid();

    report1Component.LoadData();

});
```

**Question**

How do I load the data into the grid and make it work smooth, even for the very first time?

Comment: Have you tried it out outside of the panel?

Comment: Just tried, no luck.

Comment: Oh, remove all of the scrolling stuff:   "scrollX": true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            scroller: true,

Comment: Removing scrollCollapse: true helped me. I need the scroller:true as I am using the extension.